# FreeIPA-Client sssd.service warning/failure

Tags: freeipa, sssd

This warning is while installing ipa-client in ubuntu.

```
Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain mode
Warning failed to create cache: usr.sbin.sssd
Job for sssd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sssd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
sssd.service couldn't start.
```

After Installation, I couldn't not able to start the service.(Please refer below)`enter code here`

```
â— sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-10-08 23:25:12 ; 36s ago
 Main PID: 3500 (code=exited, status=4)

: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
: Configuration file: /etc/sssd/sssd.conf does not exist.
: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
: sssd.service: Unit entered failed state.
: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And while configuring ipa - `ipa-client-install`

```
Joining realm failed: libcurl failed to execute the HTTP POST transaction, explaining:  SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid

Installation failed. Rolling back changes.
IPA client is not configured on this system.
```

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, why it was failing while joining to the IPA Server. Actually this is due to **date and time** between server and client. Both IPA server and client date and time must be same. If date&time is different, then the client wasn’t able to join IPA server.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What was the date & time set to on the client & what was it on the server, & what did you change to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Both IPA server and client date and time must be same. If date&time is different, then the client wasn’t able to join IPA server.